# Creating Forms with JS within Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Is it possible to create forms within the CANVAS element im using the processingJS library but cannot find any support for forms?

Comment: By "forms", you mean "fill in the blank forms" that you'd normally do with `<input>` elements etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly put other HTML elements in a canvas, but nothing's stopping you from positioning HTML elmements *over* a canvas. Firefox <strike>5 is going to have</strike> 4 has a mechanism to allow a canvas (or anything else) to be used as a [background for another element](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/08/mozelement/), so with a facility like that you could draw into a canvas that's set up as the background for your `<form>` (or whatever).